# Does $\sum n $ converge p-adically?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

Does $\sum n $ converge p-adically, I have worked out  $v_p(n) \leqslant log(n)/log(p) $

not sure how to conclude from this

I want to prove this using the result that it converges p-adically iff $v_p(n)$ tends to infinity as n tends to infinity

Comment: Since the $p$-adic valuation of $q$ for $q$ a prime different from $p$ is $1$, and since this occurs infinitely often, the sum cannot converge.

Comment: Since a series converges if and only if the general term converges to $0$, the answer is no.

Comment: Have you looked at examples? Like $p=5$ and $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,\cdots$? Do you understand that the condition for convergence is that the $v_p(*)$ go to infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series $\sum a_n$ converges $p$-adically if and only if $a_n$ tends to zero $p$-adically, because the $p$-adic absolute value is non-archimedean. Now, the sequence $n$ does not tend to zero $p$-adically, as its extract $1+p^n$ does not converge to zero, as it has constant $p$-adic absolute value equal to $1$.

Comment: I want to prove this using the result that it converges p-adically iff vp(n) tends to infinity as n tends to infinity

Comment: Well then, as $|x|_p = p^{-v_p (n)}$, you see that $|n|_p$ converges to zero iff $v_p(n)$ tends to infinity, and $v_p(1+p^n) = 0$, so that $v_p(1+p^n)$ does not tend to $+\infty$...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your notation what is |x|p and |n|p?

Comment: $|x|_p$ is the $p$-adic absolute value of $x$, $|n|_p$ is the one of $n$... These are basic notions, maybe you should work them out first.

Comment: Could it have been sufficient to say vp(n) is strictly less than log(n) which converges to infinity?

Comment: No. Being strictly smaller than something converging to $+\infty$ does not imply that you don't converge to $+\infty$, whereas the point here was showing that $v_p(n)$ does not converge to $+\infty$. Here again, that kind of stuff is (supposed to be) basic stuff for someone tackling $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: Ah I see, it's just we haven't covered p-adic absolute values, we've only looked at convergence of vp(n) so I was a little lost

Answer (score 1):

No -- whenever you add something that is *not* a multiple of $p$, the $p$-adic distance between the previous and current partial sum is $1$.

So the sequence of partial sums can't be Cauchy.

Comment: I want to prove this using the result that it converges p-adically iff vp(n) tends to infinity as n tends to infinity

Comment: @TheProblem: And what is your $v_p(n)$ when $n$ is not a multiple of $p$?